# Update rows of whole table depending on values of previous row entry

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to update current row's Cnt_Per_Item by searching for value at previous(former trigger date) of same ITEM and add +1 or -1. Cnt_Per_Item +1 if Fault (Cnt_Per_Item-1 if ok)
I have found some queries for searching previous or next row, but I only get single output. Now I want to update the whole table. Default value now for Cnt_Per_Item is NULL.
(40.000-entries and growing.)
[example how Table should work][1]

```
    ITEM       | trigger                        | Fault/OK     Cnt_Per_Item

    |1          |2016-04-08 11:49:15.483          |Fault          |5|
    |2          |2016-04-08 12:49:15.383          |Fault          |1|
    |4          |2016-05-08 11:49:15.723          |Fault          |1|
    |2          |2016-07-09 00:49:15.503          |Fault          |2|
    |1          |2016-04-08 11:50:24.103          |OK             |4|
    |1          |2016-08-08 13:06:35.157          |Fault          |5|
    |1          |2016-08-11 13:06:35.277          |Fault          |6|
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large table, this will not be efficient.  But you can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set cnt_per_item = coalesce( (select sum(case when fault_ok = 'fault' then 1 else -1 end)
                                  from t t2
                                  where t2.item = t.item and t2.trigger <= t.trigger
                                 ), 0);
```

Comment: Sorry currently I'm not able to show a little example of the table. (Maybe it would  show that for each line the previous line has to be searched. And after found the nearest date then counter of found rows has to be taken and used to update current row's value.